# react ag-grid table not displaying and shows an error

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

what i want to do is to display a component that contains an ag-grid table, a side bar and an other component that is an other ag-grid table. well when i start the program it goes well at the begining but when the i go to the route where the component i told you should be displayed appears this error message:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `ConsultaNiños`.

here is the code for the `ConsultaNiños` where everything all the others are:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import SideBar from './SideBar'
import AgGridReact from 'ag-grid-react'
import TablaDatosNiño from './TablaDatosNiño'
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine-dark.css';

class ConsultaNiños extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            columnDefs:[{
                headerName:'Nombre', field:'Nombres'
            }],
            rowData:null
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>{/*this is the sidebar*/}
                    <SideBar></SideBar>
                </div>

                {/**here is the table that i made in this same component*/}
                <div className='ag-theme-alpine-dark'style={{height:'600px'}}>
                    <AgGridReact
                        columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                        rowData={this.state.rowData}
                    /> 
                </div>

                {/**this is the other table i want to display*/}
                <div>
                    <TablaDatosNiño></TablaDatosNiño>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ConsultaNiños
```

here is the code for the other table the component `TablaDatosNiños`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import AgGridReact from 'ag-grid-react'
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine-dark.css';

class ConsultaNiños extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            columnDefs:[{
                headername:'IDalumno',field:'idalumno'
            },{
                headername:'Nombre',field:'nombre'
            },{
                headername:'Fechadenacimiento',field:'fecha de nacimiento'
            },{
                headername:'Horario',field:'horario'
            },
```

it goes on like that with a lot of columns. Then here is the rowData and the render method:

```
rowData:[]
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {/**tabla con los datos del niño*/}
                <div className='ag-theme-alpine-dark'style={{height:'600px'}}>
                    <AgGridReact
                        columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                        rowData={this.state.rowData}
                    /> 
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ConsultaNiños
```

here is my app.js file:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './layout/login.js';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Matriculacion from './pages/Matriculacion';
import Medicinas from './pages/Medicinas';
import IngEg from './pages/IngEg';
import ConsultaNiños from './layout/ConsultaNiños'




 class  App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = '/' render = {pops => (
              <Fragment>
                <Login></Login>
              </Fragment>
            )}/>
            <Route exact path = '/Matriculacion' component = {Matriculacion}/>
            <Route exact path = '/Medicinas' component = {Medicinas}/>
            <Route exact path = '/Ingresos_Egresos' component = {IngEg}/>
            <Route exact path = '/Table' component={ConsultaNiños}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>    
      </Router>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

the route that opens the component is the /Table.

well i researched for this and found what could be a possibe solution by adding curly braces to the import of the `{ConsultaNiños}` but now it shows this error message:

Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'ConsultaNiños' is not exported from './layout/ConsultaNiños'.

well that message means that there should be an error on exporting the component but when i delete the curly braces in the import of `ConsultaNiños` and delete both of the tables in the component it works perfectly and with any export errors. meaning that the problem may be directly in the ag-grid tables components but the sintaxis seems having no mistakes so there is the problem.

i would be very grateful if you could help me <3

Comment: i found the solution. It is just to create a component for each table apart and render them in a parent component which can be used as a bridge among the components to share information among them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well what i was trying to do was to render everything in the same component i was trying to create the table. Aparently this is not valid because the grid configuration so i just made each table in a diferent component and related them in a third component in which i added both tables, this third component works as an intermediate between the tables and allow communication between the tables via props